# which AWS configuation is best for my project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to migrate my web application to AWS. May I know which configuration I have to take from AWS, following are my requirement

- Around 1TB of data
- Daily around 100K visitors
- 2k real-time visitors

Answer (score 3):

**Nobody will be able to give you this information!**

The only way to know what type of configuration can meet a particular workload is to **test the actual workload**. You should use a testing system that can simulate the typical workload that users would place on the system, and monitor the performance of the system.

This is because there are many factors that can impact system performance:

- Size of EC2 instances and databases
- The number of instances (one server vs multiple servers)
- The number of simultaneous users
- What the users are doing (browsing, searching, purchasing)
- Whether the system is data-intensive or CPU-intensive
- How well the program is written
- ...and many more!

If anybody tells you that they can predict system performance without actually testing the system, then they are lying. The only way to know is to actually put load on the system and then measure metrics such as memory, disk access, latency and throughput.

There are plenty of tools available to help with such a simulation, such as: [Benchmarking with Bees with Machine Guns](http://blog.samstefan.co.uk/load-testing-with-bees-with-machine-guns/)